# How to handle multiple line JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a string from an ajax call. That variable directly comes from a text field from the MySQL database. But after getting that value I'm unable to console log it. By Console debug it is saying multiline error.

I'm giving the variable which I need to console.log.

```
var str = "Hello Sir/Madam
            Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>




            Warm Regards,";
```

how to `console.log` what comes from AJAX?

Comment: You can use template strings, though you may need to transpile your code depending on where it will be used.

Comment: If he receives this via Ajax, where does he put those?

Comment: @DanFromGermany, good point and I think that bears further explanation. OP, please update your question with exactly how that variable is set, your specific `console.log` invocation, and the actual error it throws.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for Strings that span multiple lines. Template literals are enclosed with backticks (`).

```js
var message = `Hello Sir/Madam
                Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>
    
    
    
    
                Warm Regards,`;
console.log(message);
```

For better browser support, you could just concatenate the String and use `"\n"` for new lines.

```js
var message = "Hello Sir/Madam\n"+
"                Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>"
+"\n\n\n\n"+       
"                    Warm Regards,";
console.log(message);
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know you can use **\**

```
"First Line \
 Second Line \
 Third Line"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = `Hello Sir/Madam
            Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>




            Warm Regards,`;
```

https://codepen.io/pixel-lab/pen/wxbxKO

Comment: While this might answer the OP's question, please do not post code-only answers; include an explanation of your code and/or solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use backticks (`) to allow for a multiline string.

```
var str = `Hello Sir/Madam
            Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>




            Warm Regards,`;

console.log(str);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y5hs9r0b/

The following is invalid syntax and js will be unable to parse it.

```
var str = "Hello Sir/Madam
            Please find password sent on your email.<br><br>\n545abea<br><br>




            Warm Regards,";
```

If however you are getting the data from a database, it should already be in a variable in which case you can just `console.log` the existing var.